# How to make a disabled DatePicker look like its enabled

Tags: css, javafx, datepicker

Is it possible to have a `DatePicker` object in JavaFX disabled, looking like an enabled `DatePicker`?

Or, how to disable the popup window for the selection of the date ?

I tried with:

```
myDp.setDisable(true);
myDp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
```

but no other ideas.. any help?

[image: http://s2.postimg.org/5j3s5nxt5/Immaginedp.png]

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

I used in my code:

```
myDp.setDisable(true);
myDp.setStyle(" -fx-opacity: 1.0;"); 
myDp.getEditor().setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1.0;")
```

when I want that it looks like if it's disabled, 
while if I want that it looks like if it's disabled:

```
myDp.setStyle(" -fx-opacity: 0.4;"); 
myDp.getEditor().setStyle("-fx-opacity: 0.4;")
```

*thanks to ItachiUchiha*

Answer (score 0):

A single solution can work for both.

Keep your DatePicker **disabled** and add the following css :

```
/* For date-picker */
.date-picker:disabled {
     -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}

/* For date-picker textfield */
.date-picker > .date-picker-display-node:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: ok, thankyou very much!
Anyway, because I needed to use the function SetStyle(), because there are some cases in which I have to whow the datepicker disabled, I used:
`
        myDp.setStyle("     -fx-opacity: 1.0;");
        myDp.getEditor().setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1.0;");
`

Comment: Is that a question? Because if it is, I don't get it ;)

Comment: no, not a question, just said that  I used your solution with the 'setStyle()' function ;)

Comment: @Matteo You can write a separate answer to your question. Do not edit your question and add answers to it.